# Is there a way to match first element without any text before it?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

For example, I would like to only extract the `em` element from the following one,

```
<p><em>xxx</em>yyy<p>
```

but not the `em` from the following one.

```
<p>some extra text<em>xxx</em>yyy<p>
```

Is there a way to do so with xpath?

Comment: Would you want to select `em` in  `<p><i>some extra text</i><em>xxx</em>yyy</p>` ?

Comment: How many `em` should be selected in `<p><em>x1</em><em>x2</em></p>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `preceding-sibling` check like below:

```py
print(tree.xpath("//em[not(preceding-sibling::text())]/text()"))
```

With this HTML:

```html
<p><em>xxx</em>yyy</p>

<p>some extra text<em>xxx</em>yyy</p>

<p><em>yes</em>anotherText</p><p>test<em>no</em></p><p><em>yes2</em>Text</p>
```

Outputs:

```
['xxx', 'yes', 'yes2']
```